# PlayerSettings Validation: Requested build target group (15) doesn't exist; #define symbols for scripting won't be added

Tags: unity3d

Появились ошибки(см.фото) в Unity3D, которые я никак не могу исправить, даже читая зарубежные форумы[[ссылка](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/errors-appear-in-console-on-importing-character-standard-asset)], где с такой проблемой справились(возможно, что-то не так делаю, я не отрицаю).

[image: ошибка Unity3D - PlayerSettings Validation: Requested build target group (15) doesn't exist; #define symbols for scripting won't be added.]
Если вдруг, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой - пожалуйста отпишите, как Вы ее решили?

Comment: Если не билдить игру, то она запускается? (В эдиторе)

Comment: И на какую платформу билдите Android/Pc?

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer ПК. Игра запускалась в эдиторе